# Collection overview changed after purging

Tags: modeling, objects

I think the picture shows everything. How could i get it back to normal, like before?!

#1 Before purging
[image]

#2 After purging
[image]

I hope someone sumbled across a simliar problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type to view layer:

[image]